# Is it possible sorting a table with non-database driven data?

Tags: theming

I am creating tables, using data from services. This data is not stored in a db.

But while I have been able to theme it using tableselect, I can't get sorting to work. Adding sort on fields, expects me to also integrate that to a query, for things to work. So even though I get the ascending and descending arrow, the data is not actually being sorted.

Comment: *[If the question is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. Questions that are substantially about code, where the code is not shown, are possibly closed.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*

Comment: If you mean does Drupal core have that functionality, then no, you'd need to implement it yourself

Comment: I am using tableselect via my form but this is not a code related question....Tableselect sort works on query based data, and not any other custom data.